# insertAfter clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup;

```
<div class="model-timeline">
        <p>Text</p>
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="span-blank-5"></div>
            <div class="time-span-1"></div>
            <div class="time-span-2"></div>
            <div class="time-span-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="model-timeline">
        <p>Text</p>
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="span-blank-5"></div>
            <div class="time-span-1"></div>
            <div class="time-span-2"></div>
            <div class="time-span-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and script;

```
    $('[class*="time-span"]').on('click', function () {
    $('.model-detail-panel').insertAfter('.timeline').slideDown('fast', function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

I need to insert a new div 'model-detail-panel' after clicking one of the time-span classes.

This new div should appear after the timeline class and only inside the parent div of the timeline class that was clicked.

The code I have is inserting the div, but its adding it after every timeline class which is not the behaviour I need.

How can I modify my code to target only the clicked parent of the element, hence inserting the div once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 $('.model-detail-panel').insertAfter($(this).parent()) ...
```

This will insert your panel after the parent of the clicked element.